# Matplotlib: How to display and position 2 YAxis BOTH on the Left side of my graph

Tags: python, matplotlib, yaxis

I have found this [nice exemple](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/ticks_and_spines/multiple_yaxis_with_spines.html). But I try to do something like this:

[image]

with my Velocity YAxis on the left side, not on the right one. Any tips?

Thanks by advance to the community.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok here is the trick

1. Add a negative offset to your left side:
   `par2.spines["left"].set_position(("axes", -0.2))`
2. set the tick on the left: `par2.yaxis.tick_left()`
3. set the label position: `par2.yaxis.set_label_position("left")`
4. Switch on the left spines: `par2.spines["left"].set_visible(True)`

So the final complete code is:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


def make_patch_spines_invisible(ax):
    ax.set_frame_on(True)
    ax.patch.set_visible(False)
    for sp in ax.spines.values():
        sp.set_visible(False)


fig, host = plt.subplots()
fig.subplots_adjust(left=0.25)

par1 = host.twinx()
par2 = host.twinx()

# Offset the right spine of par2.  The ticks and label have already been
# placed on the right by twinx above.
par2.spines["left"].set_position(("axes", -0.2))
par2.yaxis.tick_left()
par2.yaxis.set_label_position("left")

# Having been created by twinx, par2 has its frame off, so the line of its
# detached spine is invisible.  First, activate the frame but make the patch
# and spines invisible.
make_patch_spines_invisible(par2)
# Second, show the right spine.
par2.spines["left"].set_visible(True)

p1, = host.plot([0, 1, 2], [0, 1, 2], "b-", label="Density")
p2, = par1.plot([0, 1, 2], [0, 3, 2], "r-", label="Temperature")
p3, = par2.plot([0, 1, 2], [50, 30, 15], "g-", label="Velocity")

host.set_xlim(0, 2)
host.set_ylim(0, 2)
par1.set_ylim(0, 4)
par2.set_ylim(1, 65)

host.set_xlabel("Distance")
host.set_ylabel("Density")
par1.set_ylabel("Temperature")
par2.set_ylabel("Velocity")

host.yaxis.label.set_color(p1.get_color())
par1.yaxis.label.set_color(p2.get_color())
par2.yaxis.label.set_color(p3.get_color())

tkw = dict(size=4, width=1.5)
host.tick_params(axis='y', colors=p1.get_color(), **tkw)
par1.tick_params(axis='y', colors=p2.get_color(), **tkw)
par2.tick_params(axis='y', colors=p3.get_color(), **tkw)
host.tick_params(axis='x', **tkw)

lines = [p1, p2, p3]

host.legend(lines, [l.get_label() for l in lines])

plt.show()
```